# Is there any way how i could trigger a app present in some other android phone but in the same network to run and do some work for me

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, remote-access

I am creating a app 'A' which needs images of a nearby place 'XYZ' as input.So i have created a app 'B' which takes photo .

Now, I am struck at this part present below, does anyone know how i could do it?

Whenever i want a pic of the place 'XYZ' i click button on my app 'A' 'Get Image', And this should trigger the app 'B' present in the place 'XYZ' and start the app so that it clicks the image and sends it back to my app 'A'.

I have tried creating sockets in both app and send request from app 'A' to the IP address at some port number of app 'B' , but this is not working if my app is removed from memory ,i.e its not in running state ,bcz app 'B' socket is not listening when its removed from memory.

Comment: use a service in `B`, but service can also be stopped, in that case I think you need System Access

Comment: I will try using service ,thanks a lot!  one more thing , can you tell me how i can trigger app B from app A and send the picture back to A?